# Generically convert bytes to integers

Tags: c++, bitwise, c++20

I wanted to know If there was a way to make it more versatile or shorter/simpler. Here's the code:

```
// Take only std::byte parameter and return an unsigned integral
constexpr auto bytes_to_uint(std::same_as<std::byte> auto... bytes) -> std::unsigned_integral auto {
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(bytes);

    // Integral types large enough to hold N bytes
    using types = std::tuple<
        std::uint8_t,
        std::uint16_t,
        std::uint32_t,
        std::uint32_t,
        std::uint64_t,
        std::uint64_t,
        std::uint64_t,
        std::uint64_t
    >;
    
    using result = std::tuple_element_t<N, types>;
    
    return [&]<std::size_t... S>(std::index_sequence<S...>) {
        // Accumulate the part of the number using the bitwise or operator for each bytes
        return ((static_cast<result>(bytes) << CHAR_BIT * (N - S - 1)) | ... );
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

It is meant to be used like this:

```
bytes_to_uint(std::byte{0xaa}, std::byte{0xbb}); // std::uint16_t: 0xaabb

bytes_to_uint(
    std::byte{0x11},
    std::byte{0x22},
    std::byte{0x33},
    std::byte{0x44}
); // std::uint32_t: 0x11223344
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function signature strikes me as difficult to read, thanks to the constraint `std::same_as<std::byte> auto...` and the trailing "return type" `std::unsigned_integral auto`. I might rather write something like

```
constexpr auto bytes_to_uint(std::initializer_list<std::byte> bytes) {
```

...Ah, but then you couldn't use `bytes.size()` as a constant expression; I see.
So I'd think about writing an overload set, like this:

```
constexpr std::uint8_t bytes_to_uint(std::byte a) {
    return a;
}
constexpr std::uint16_t bytes_to_uint(std::byte a, std::byte b) {
    return (a << 8) | b;
}
constexpr std::uint32_t bytes_to_uint(std::byte a, std::byte b, std::byte c, std::byte d) {
    return (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;
}
```

But I guess this is messy because you need 16 different overloads. You can't even use default function arguments, because you want `bytes_to_uint(a,b,c)` to be equal to `bytes_to_uint(0,a,b,c)` and not `bytes_to_uint(a,b,c,0)`. Of course you could still write

```
#define B std::byte
constexpr std::uint8_t bytes_to_uint(B a)
  { return bytes_to_uint(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a); }
constexpr std::uint16_t bytes_to_uint(B a, B b)
  { return bytes_to_uint(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a,b); }
constexpr std::uint32_t bytes_to_uint(B a, B b, B c)
  { return bytes_to_uint(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a,b,c); }
constexpr std::uint32_t bytes_to_uint(B a, B b, B c, B d)
  { return bytes_to_uint(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a,b,c,d); }
constexpr std::uint64_t bytes_to_uint(B a, B b, B c, B d, B e)
  { return bytes_to_uint(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a,b,c,d,e); }
[...22 more lines...]
#undef B
```

but I bet you don't want to do that. Okay, let's stick with the templatey thing you did.

---

```
using result = std::tuple_element_t<N, types>;
```

I'd rather see this dependent typedef use `CamelCase` (like a template parameter) or `suffixedwith_type` (like an STL member typedef). Calling it `result` makes it look too much like a variable, and makes it hard to pick out the one place where you use it.

Instead of spending 13 lines and a `<tuple>` dependency, I'd rather just do

```
using ResultType = std::conditional_t<
    (N == 1), std::uint8_t, std::conditional_t<
    (N == 2), std::uint16_t, std::conditional_t<
    (N <= 4), std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>>>;
```

Which reminds me, you need something like

```
static_assert(N <= 16);
```

to stop you from trying to handle an argument list of 17 bytes or more.

And I didn't even notice until I tried it in Godbolt, but, you've got an off-by-one bug here! You meant `tuple_element_t<N-1, types>`. Remember that indexing always starts at zero (everywhere except `<regex>`).

---

If you don't like `conditional_t`, another option is to use plain old `if`s. Factor out the computation while it's still parameterized on `ResultType`, and then use an `if-else` chain to decide on the right type to plug in for `ResultType` later:

```
auto do_it = [&]<class ResultType, std::size_t... S>(ResultType, std::index_sequence<S...>) {
    return ((static_cast<ResultType>(bytes) << CHAR_BIT * (N - S - 1)) | ... );
};
if constexpr (N == 1) {
    return do_it(std::uint8_t{}, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
} else if constexpr (N == 2) {
    return do_it(std::uint16_t{}, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
} else if constexpr (N <= 4) {
    return do_it(std::uint32_t{}, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
} else if constexpr (N <= 8) {
    return do_it(std::uint64_t{}, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

---

Even better, permit the compiler to do the math at its preferred bit-width (which is 64 bits on all the desktop platforms *I* care about) and then truncate it at the end. This produces similar codegen and reads nicer yet:

```
std::uint64_t result = [&]<std::size_t... S>( std::index_sequence<S...>) {
    return ((static_cast<std::uint64_t>(bytes) << CHAR_BIT * (N - S - 1)) | ... );
}(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
if constexpr (N == 1) {
    return std::uint8_t(result);
} else if constexpr (N == 2) {
    return std::uint16_t(result);
} else if constexpr (N <= 4) {
    return std::uint32_t(result);
} else {
    return std::uint64_t(result);
}
```

---

You have another bug when `N == 1` (besides the off-by-one bug). When `N == 1`, the fold-expression has no `|` operations at all, and so it's just a `uint8_t` shifted by zero. That shift expression has type `int`. Which is not an unsigned integral type. So your return-type-constraint fails!

This is just another reason to do all the math *first* in `uint64_t`, and then cast down to `uint8_t` right before you return, as shown in my last example above.

Writing any test cases would have caught both this bug and the off-by-one bug. Test cases are always important! Especially when you're planning to put the code up for public review. (Or for review by coworkers, for that matter.)

---

Finally, I recommend parentheses to clarify the precedence of `x << CHAR_BIT * y`. In context it's obvious what you *expected* the precedence to be; but as a reader, I'm not sure you're right. Put the parentheses so that I don't have to think about it even for a second.

However, in this context, that's a very minor point, because you clearly aren't expecting anybody to *read* the expression `((static_cast<result>(bytes) << CHAR_BIT * (N - S - 1)) | ... )`. It's a "trust me" line of code.

It's also silly to pretend that `CHAR_BIT` is relevant here. This code explodes spectacularly if `CHAR_BIT` is anything other than `8`. So just write `8`; and if you are *compelled* to work in a reference to `CHAR_BIT`, do so by writing

```
static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8);
```

at the top of the function.